# Why does it keep rounding when I use BigDecimal

Tags: java, bigdecimal

So I am trying to calculate my average goals blocked by dividing how many I stopped by how many shots have been taken. How can I stop it from rounding my average

counter = goals blocked
goalCounter = goals scored

```
avg.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        BigDecimal avgCalc = new BigDecimal(counter/goalCounter);
        tvDisplayAvg.setText("Goal Avg: " + avgCalc);
    }
});
```

So I got it to divide and get decimals but is there a way to set a limit of only dividing to the thousandths place?

Comment: what type is counter and goalcounter?

Answer (score 5):

your rounding comes probably from `counter/goalCounter`
if you are using big decimal, stay with it.

```
avg.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        BigDecimal c = new BigDecimal(counter);
        BigDecimal g = new BigDecimal(goalCounter);
        BigDecimal answer=c.divide(g);

        tvDisplayAvg.setText("Goal Avg: " + amswer.toString());
    }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

The problem might be that `counter` and `goalCounter` are both ints. Try casting one of them to double when you divide (e.g. `counter/(double)goalCounter`). This is because if Java sees you dividing two integers, the result will also be an integer.

If they are not ints (i.e. they are floats or doubles), the float and double types have limited precision, and the BigDecimal class was created to rectify this situation. Make two BigDecimals - one for each variable - and then assign avgCalc to their quotient.

Comment: double is very bad idea if you want big decimal precision

Comment: Which is why my answer has two parts.